# Is there a way to tell if a dataset or object is assigned to a variable of another object?

Tags: delphi

So I'm getting an error from a third party library that "cannot delete table because it is open by another dataset" and I'm having a hard time finding the dataset that is using it because we do a lot of runtime dataset assignments. I've created a test app and the only way to get this error is by having an object have a property assigned to a dataset. My questions is: Is there any good way to find if the address of a dataset is assigned to a property of another variable?

For example, if I have:

```
ObjX: TDateset;
ObjY: TAdoQuery;

procedure Test(TestDS: TDataset);
begin
    ObjY.Dataset := TestDS;
end

procedure Form1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Test(ObjX);
end
```

And if for some reason I don't know that ObjY exists or that it has its data property set, is there anyway to use ONLY ObjX and maybe some other debug tool to find that ObjY has a property assigned to ObjX?

Comment: I think you may be going about this the wrong way.  What you should be doing, imo, when the error occurs is to do an application-wide search of all the forms and datamodules currently instanced to see which of them contains a dataset referencing the same **physical** dataset as the one producing the error. This may involve examining object properties, but it's not just those that you need to look at: Suppose f.i. that some query object is referencing the physical dataset in a Sql SELECT statement - this might not be apparent from a property identity of the sort you are asking about.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you, that sounds like a good idea. I'm still a bit fresh in the Delphi world, I'm using Rad Studio 10.2, how do I go about doing search of all the forms and datamodules instanced? Our application has about 100+ forms all instantiated in the dpr using Application.CreateForm. I have examined all the objects that I thought might have a property assigned to the one that is throwing an error, but we have so many I can't find the problematic one.

Comment: Well, if they are all instantiated in the Dpr it should be pretty easy - you can see if they are all owned by the Application object and, assuiming that they are, do a recursive search of it and the objects it owns.

Comment: Okay, I guess I just don't know how to do a search of the objects that it owns in Delphi.

Comment: Well, TApplication descends from TComponent, and TComponent has a `Components` property (as does TForm and TDataModule) that you can use to iterate its sub-components.

Comment: Ok cool Thanks. I've been using the Debug->Inspect on application then clicking on the Fcomponents property opens up an inspect for FComponents, then I see  the address of all objects in the FItems property of FComponents. I can click on an address and open the object, but how do I employ a recursive search using these windows to find what I'm looking for?
Edit: Okay I think I finally comprehended what you're telling me. I am going to do a search for the address of the problematic table in the list of components and their properties. Hopefully I can find the object that is holding the table.

Comment: Okay well this won't work because Application does not give any info about its components after the instantiation in the dpr is completed. It goes from Having a list of all the properties to just saying "Application: Application" when I reach the point in the code where the exception is thrown and I can't find any way to circumvent this.

Comment: It will work:  I wasn't talking about doing it in the debugger,  YOu need to write some lgiing code which executes at run-ttime when the problem occurs.

Comment: Ohhhh, alright that makes sense. Do you have any hints or direction on how to do that? I have not used the Application object at all in any code and I'm having trouble even accessing it in the unit where the exception occurs because the unit is not instantiated with Application.CreateForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**I've updated this to include an alternarive method of searching
components for references to a given table name, see below.

The sample project below shows how to capture the live objects in the Application
object and check whether any of them s seems to contain a reference (by name) to
a given table.  In this example the check is triggered by a button-click, but obviously in
your case you would trigger it when the problem occurs.  Any components which match the
`TableRef` value are logged to a TMemo.  It does not cover all the possibilities, for example ownerless Components, but should give you the general idea.

As you'll see, it depends on type-casting components to specific TDataSet descendants
and then checking possibly-relevant properties of them.  In my case I'm looking for
a reference to a table named "authors" in a number of TAdoDataset types, specifically
TAdoQuery and TAdoTable.  You will
have to adapt the code in `CheckComponentForTableRef` to the specific dataset type(s)
you are using.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckComponentForTableRef(AComponent: TComponent;
  const TableRef: String);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if AComponent is TAdoQuery then begin
    if Pos(LowerCase(TableRef), AComponent.Name) > 0 then
      LogReference(AComponent, 'ComponentName', TableRef);
    if Pos(LowerCase(TableRef), TAdoQuery(AComponent).Sql.Text) > 0 then
      LogReference(AComponent, 'SqlText', TableRef);
  end;
  if AComponent is TAdoTable then begin
    if Pos(LowerCase(TableRef), TAdoTable(AComponent).TableName) > 0 then
      LogReference(AComponent, 'TableName', TableRef);
  end;

  // the following recursively examines AComponent's sub-components
  for i := 0 to AComponent.ComponentCount - 1 do
   CheckComponentForTableRef(AComponent.Components[i], TableRef);
end;

procedure TForm1.FindTableRefs(const TableRef: String);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    //  The Application object's Components include the forms
    //  and datamodules created with it as Owner.
    CheckComponentForTableRef(Application.Components[i], TableRef);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LogReference(AComponent: TComponent;
  const AProperty : String;
  const TableRef: String);
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := AComponent.Name;
  if AComponent.Owner <> Nil then
    S := AComponent.Owner.Name + ':' + S;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Component: %s, Property: %s, TableRef: %s', [S, AProperty, TableRef]));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FindTableRefs('authors');
end;
```

**Update**

An obvious disadvantage of the method suggested above is that the `CheckComponentForTableRef`
method requires typecasts for the specific TDataSet descendants used in the project.

The following shows an alternative method, which involves examining string representations
of the project components.  This avoids the need for customizing the `CheckComponentForTableRef`
and so the example below could be used "as-is".  The only obvious downside is that the
string representations which are examined are of the published properties of the component;  however
as the Object Inspector operates on these and is how database accesses are often set up,
this disadvantage may be more theoretical than actual.

```
function TForm1.ComponentToString(AComponent : TComponent) : String;
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Writer : TWriter;
begin
  //  Note:  There may be a more direct way of doing the following, without
  //  needing the TMemoryStream, MS
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Writer := TWriter.Create(MS, 4096);

  try
    Writer.Root := Self;
    Writer.WriteSignature;
    Writer.WriteComponent(AComponent);
    Writer.FlushBuffer;
    MS.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MS, SS);
    Result := SS.DataString;
  finally
    Writer.Free;
    MS.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SearchForString(const TableRef : String);
var
  i : Integer;

  procedure SearchComponentForString(AComponent : TComponent; const TableRef : String);
  var
    i : Integer;
    S : String;
  begin
    // the following line prevents the contents of Memo1, which is
    //  used for logging, being searched
    if AComponent = Memo1 then exit;

    S := ComponentToString(AComponent);
    if Pos(LowerCase(TableRef), LowerCase(S)) > 0 then begin
       LogReference(AComponent, S, TableRef);
       Exit;  //  TableRef found, so don't recurse into sub-components
    end;
    for i := 0 to AComponent.ComponentCount - 1 do
     SearchComponentForString(AComponent.Components[i], TableRef);
  end;
begin
  for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do
    SearchComponentForString(Application.Components[i], TableRef);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SearchForString('authors');
end;
```